# Create Child-Applications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im have coded a small CMS for creating FB_Pages. The CMS works great, but i wan't that the users publish their new generated pages automaticly.
I have created a main application to get permissions (managa my pages etc...). I can create a new tabs on existing userpages. But i have no idea how to publish the new generated Page in it.
Is it possible to create a "child applications" via graph api?.

Comment: See: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7073146/how-to-register-a-facebook-application-dynamically-via-graph-api-like-wildfireapp/7185214#7185214

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is currently not possible.  Users will have to create their own apps.